# Driving LEDs with USB datalines

Tags: led, usb, communication, usb-device, hardware

can I use a schmitt trigger to drive LED with USB data lines D+ and D-?
I use a USB2.0 Full speed.

Thank you,

Comment: Why do you want to do this? You won't get anything meaningful other than flickering.

Comment: What should the LED be good for? Indicate USB traffic? The host sends a SOF packet every 1ms and pulls each IN endpoint at least every 1ms. So there is constant activity on the bus even if no real data is transferred. For a meaningful indicator, a rather sophisticated circuit is needed. If you are working with a MCU, it's probably easier to control the LED from the MCU.

Comment: thank you for your response, but this is what is written in the design request. thay want LEDs in USB D+ and D-

Comment: Yes you can. I think, it's ok even to use a single transistor buffer circuit for each line.

Comment: *but this is what is written in the design request. thay want LEDs in USB D+ and D-* Realize that whoever wrote that "design request" might be unaware of what is mentioned in the comments here (that you'd get constantly flickering LEDs). A good designer will want to understand **why** this request exists, so ask for extra information. If you all agree that flickering LEDs is OK, then by all means continue. I challenge specifications all the time and that is appreciated (also by our customers) as it makes sure we all agree on what the circuit will need to do.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie, actually, by watching D+ and D- with buffered LEDs, some very useful info can be obtained - first, if the connect event ever occurs (a pull on D+ or D-). Then you can see the speed of link - LS or FS. Then you can notice the USB_RESET momentarily, usually twice during enumeration. And you can see if the link enters SUSPEND (no blinking). You can attach a small MCU to the buffers, and you will get something like this device, https://www.kage-electronics.com/resources/USB_link_monitor_v109.282133547.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, provided that the Schmitt triggers don’t overload the USB lines you should be ok.  Whether that’s achievable depends on the configuration of your circuit.